# Получение данных из Mysql C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Необходимо получить balance по userid 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но выводит цифру 1

```
string balance = $"SELECT balance FROM users WHERE userid = {test.Messages[0].UserId}";
MySqlCommand bquery = new MySqlCommand(balance, conn);
comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();

vk.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
{
      ChatId = 101,
      Message = "Ваш аккаунт уже зарегистрирован. Ваш баланс: " + comm1.ExecuteScalar()
});
```

Comment: Если вы делаете `SELECT`, то с какого перепугу `comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();` и `comm1.ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: @Bulson а что использовать вместо них? Извините, просто нигде нет понятного для меня урока

Comment: `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); while (reader.Read()) {...}`

Comment: @Bulson возвращает True. А мне нужно число

Comment: Покажите код, который это делает, т.е. возвращает true

Comment: @Bulson string 
MySqlDataReader reader = bquery.ExecuteReader();

                            vk.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
                            {
                                ChatId = 101,
                                Message = "Ваш аккаунт уже зарегистрирован. Ваш баланс: " + reader.Read()
                            });

Comment: Все правильно, `reader.Read()` возвращает true, когда есть запись, потому этот вызов включают в условие `while(){}`. Если вы хотите получить значение, то нужно `reader[0].ToString()`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76655/discussion-between-farid-jannatov-and-bulson).